# Installing Gapps (space problem)

Tags: google-play-store, google, 8.1-oreo, custom-roms

I have installed the custom ROM from TeamWin recovery mode for android 8.1 (don't judge ). Everything was installing fine with no errors but then I then installed Gapps, it then told me there is not enough free space on /system partition. How can I free up some space to install Gapps?

**EDIT:**

Check this [log file](https://pastebin.com/R8r3QX7E)!

Comment: Use a smaller Gapps package...

Comment: In general on a custom ROM it is recommended to use the GApps nano package. Otherwise you will have earlier or later every app installed twice (for each GApp one on the system partition and one updated app on the user data partition). Just use the nano package and download all GApps you want from PlayStore.

Comment: @acejavelin I installed the pico version and still has the same error.

Comment: Did you perform a CLEAN install? Meaning, did you wipe system, data, and caches prior to flashing? If yes, then I would suggest going to your maintainer of the ROM or the official support thread for the ROM on your device, they should have a recommended Gapps package

Comment: @acejavelin Yes I wiped the tablet clean before flashing. I'll check the forums. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two way.

1. Go to Custom Recovery and wipe **/System** partition Then, reinstall Custom ROM. (Maybe **/System** partition have problem and after doing this step that's fixed. )
2. Download Nano Variant of [gapps](https://opengapps.org/) and install on your device. It's very light. Go to **Play Store** and install other Google Application. (If you install Google Application from Google Play, they installed on **/Data** partition and **/System** partition be free.)

Comment: After I tried this, it still didn't work. I think I give up at this point.

Comment: @Leon185 Test stock rom and do steps again.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: What is the model of your phone?

Comment: Take a look at the log, I edited the question to add a log.

Comment: Link is corrupted.

Comment: Its a Asus Nexus 7 2013 Edition

Comment: Its not corrupted. It still works